# IllegalStateException: FocusRequester is not initialized during Jetpack Compose testing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-testing

I have a screen with `TextFields`. I need the first `TextField` to be automatically focused when the screen is displayed.

**Minified Example code**

```
@Composable
fun ScreenView(
    data: ScreenViewData,
) {
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val focusRequester = remember {
        FocusRequester()
    }

    LaunchedEffect(
        key1 = Unit,
    ) {
        focusRequester.requestFocus()
    }

    Scaffold() { innerPadding ->
        Column {
            OutlinedTextField(
                modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester),
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The code works without any issues.

But, in compose UI testing I am getting the following error.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
> FocusRequester is not initialized. Here are some possible fixes:
>
> 1. Remember the FocusRequester: val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
> 2. Did you forget to add a Modifier.focusRequester() ?
> 3. Are you attempting to request focus during composition? Focus requests should be made in 
>    response to some event. Eg Modifier.clickable { focusRequester.requestFocus() }

**Test code**

```
@ExperimentalAnimationApi
class ScreenViewTest {

    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    @ExperimentalMaterialApi
    @Test
    fun ScreenViewElementsAreDisplayed() {
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            MyAppTheme {
                ScreenView(
                    data = ScreenViewData(),
                )
            }
        }

        // Test fails before reaching assert statements
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug, I suggest you [report it](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=741505)

Comment: @PhilipDukhov, Ok. Created [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/206249038)

Answer (score 0):

The SDETs on my team were running into the same issue, and we ended up resolving it by creating a function in our UI utilities module.

this is what we originally had in mind

```
suspend fun CoroutineScope.requestFocus(requester: FocusRequester) {
    try {
        requester.requestFocus()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        delay(100)
        requester.requestFocus()
    }
}
```

but it turned out this worked as well

```
fun CoroutineScope.requestFocus(requester: FocusRequester) {
    requester.requestFocus()
}
```

I do hope the core issue gets a resolution soon, but in the meantime, maybe this can help some folks out.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by Scaffold, you can put LaunchedEffect and FocusRequester inside Scaffold. This helped me to solve the problem. Example code:

```
@Composable
fun ScreenView(
    data: ScreenViewData,
) {
    Scaffold() { innerPadding ->
        val focusRequester = remember {
            FocusRequester()
        }
        Column {
            OutlinedTextField(
                modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester),
            )
        }
        LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
            focusRequester.requestFocus()
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your side effect does not guarantee that the `OutlinedTextField` has finished its composition. To address this, you can request the focus within the [`onGloballyPositioned`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/layout/OnGloballyPositionedModifier#onGloballyPositioned(androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutCoordinates)) modifier, like this:

```
@Composable
fun ScreenView(
    data: ScreenViewData,
) {
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }

    // LaunchedEffect(
    //     key1 = Unit,
    // ) {
    //     focusRequester.requestFocus()
    // }

    Scaffold { innerPadding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier       
                .padding(innerPadding)
        ) {
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = "your_text_field_value",
                onValueChange = { /* TODO */ },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                    .onGloballyPositioned {
                        focusRequester.requestFocus()
                    }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this function will execute each time the global position of the `OutlinedTextField` changes. If you don't want this behaviour, consider checking a condition before requesting the focus (e.g., checking if the focus was already requested).

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this?:

val focusRequester = remember(data) {
...
}